# Spring Boot unknown column in field list

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple, single-page Spring-Boot application to which I'm trying to add 6 columns to the "licenses" Entity.

On startup, it executes a search, but the new columns apparently aren't yet in the database. So it's failing on on SQL grammar exception, as follows:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'license0_.max_ipcam_users' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:974) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1024) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:306) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.license.gen.app.web.SearchController.getAll(SearchController.java:52) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

This is the license entity, with the six new fields, starting with maxIPCamUsers. I added the @Column annotation when it failed initially, but that doesn't make a difference:

```
package com.license.gen.app.model;

import com.license.gen.app.dtos.LicenseDTO;
import com.license.gen.app.utils.Utils;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "licenses")
public class License {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String fullName;
    private String contact;
    private String requester;
    private String tag;
    private String company;
    private String companyId;
    private String template;
    private String product;
    private String expiration;
    private String macs;
    private String dashboardIDs;
    private String typeId;
    private String family;
    private String systems;
    private String attributes;

    @Column(name = "max_ipcam_users")
    private String maxIPCamUsers;

    @Column(name = "max_icr_users")
    private String maxIcrUsers;

    @Column(name = "max_lector_users")
    private String maxLectorUsers;

    @Column(name = "max_other_ftp_user")
    private String maxOtherFTPUser;

    @Column(name = "max_dws_users")
    private String maxDwsUsers;

    @Column(name = "max_rfid_users")
    private String maxRfidUsers;

    private String numRDKids;
    private String persistVariablesLimit;
    private String dataSourceLimit;

    @Column(name = "license_filename", nullable = false)
    private String licenseFilename;

    @Column(name = "url", nullable = false)
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "md5_url")
    private String md5Url;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date dateCreated = new Date();

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateUpdated = new Date();

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private User user;

    public License(LicenseDTO licenseDTO) {
        this.setFieldsFromDTO(licenseDTO);
    }

    public void setFieldsFromDTO(LicenseDTO licenseDTO) {
        this.fullName = licenseDTO.getFullName();
        this.contact = licenseDTO.getContact();
        this.requester = licenseDTO.getRequester();
        this.tag = licenseDTO.getTag();
        this.company = licenseDTO.getCompany();
        this.companyId = licenseDTO.getCompanyId();
        this.template = licenseDTO.getTemplate();
        this.product = licenseDTO.getProduct();
        this.expiration = licenseDTO.getExpiration();
        this.macs = licenseDTO.getMacs();
        this.numRDKids = licenseDTO.getNumRDKids();
        this.dashboardIDs = licenseDTO.getDashboardIDs();
        this.typeId = licenseDTO.getTypeId();
        this.family = licenseDTO.getFamily();
        this.systems = licenseDTO.getSystems();
        this.attributes = Utils.convertArrayToString(licenseDTO.getAttributesArray());
        this.licenseFilename = licenseDTO.getLicenseFilename();
        this.url = licenseDTO.getUrl();
        this.md5Url = licenseDTO.getMd5url();
        this.persistVariablesLimit = licenseDTO.getPersistVariablesLimit();
        this.dataSourceLimit = licenseDTO.getDataSourceLimit();

        this.maxIPCamUsers = licenseDTO.getMaxIPCamUsers();
        this.maxIcrUsers = licenseDTO.getMaxIcrUsers();
        this.maxLectorUsers = licenseDTO.getMaxLectorUsers();
        this.maxOtherFTPUser = licenseDTO.getMaxOtherFTPUser();
        this.maxDwsUsers = licenseDTO.getMaxDwsUsers();
        this.maxRfidUsers = licenseDTO.getMaxRfidUsers();

    }
}
```

This is the search class with the "findAll" method that's invoking SQL call that crashes:

```
package com.license.gen.app.web;



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class SearchController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SearchController.class);
    private LicenseRepository licenseRepository;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    public static String bucket;



    public SearchController(LicenseRepository licenseRepository,
                            UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.licenseRepository = licenseRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;

    }



    @GetMapping("/search")
    Collection<LicenseDTO> getAll() {

        Collection<License> licenses = licenseRepository.findAll();

        ArrayList<LicenseDTO> licenseDTOS = new ArrayList<LicenseDTO>();


        for (License license : licenses) {

            licenseDTOS.add(new LicenseDTO(license));

        }

        Collections.sort(licenseDTOS, Collections.reverseOrder());

        return licenseDTOS;
    }


    @GetMapping("/search/{searchString}")
    Collection<LicenseDTO> searchlicenses(@PathVariable String searchString)
    {

        Collection<License> licenses = licenseRepository.findBySearchString(
                searchString,
                searchString,
                searchString,
                searchString,
                searchString,
                searchString,
                searchString,
                searchString,
                searchString,
                searchString);

        ArrayList<LicenseDTO> licenseDTOS = new ArrayList<LicenseDTO>();

        for (License license : licenses) {
            licenseDTOS.add(new LicenseDTO(license));
        }

        Collections.sort(licenseDTOS, Collections.reverseOrder());

        return licenseDTOS;
    }

}
```

I have added fields before in this way and Spring Boot has handled it automatically.

An ideas why it's not longer doing so?

Answer (score 1):

I had exceeded the max row size. I had made one field huge like 10000 because it truncated once, but I reduced it to 1000 and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this property to your application.properties
it updated your schema when you change your entities without deleting data

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

you can read more about this property and the available options about initializing your database here :

[Database Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

Comment: Well, that property is already there. It seems that for some reason the cases of the names are throwing it off. When I drop the schema and re-import the data, it successfully adds these two fields: max_dws_users and max_icr_users. The rest are left out, even if I just camel-case the first letter, eg. maxIpcamUsers. I'm going drop and recreate the database again, then try giving them specific column names again.

Comment: well you can try this property 
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

if it doesn't work , you can try creating the tables by yourself with an init.sql file manually, change the hibernate.ddl-auto to none, match your @Column("name") to your column name , lemme know about the result

Comment: Strange. No matter what I try, it will accept two new columns. As soon as I add the 29th field, I get the error. Makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I had exceeded the max row size. I had made one field huge like 10000 because it truncated once, but I reduced it to 1000 and that did the trick. What a crazy think